# Rename files within folders to folder names while retaining extensions

Tags: bash, shell

I have a large repository of media files that follow torrent naming conventions- something unpleasant to read. At one point, I had properly named the folders that contain said files, but not want to dump all the .avi, .mkv, etc files into my main media directory using a bash script.

Overview:
Current directory tree:

```
Proper Movie Title/
->Proper.Movie.Title.2013.avi
->Proper.Movie.Title.2013.srt
Title 2/
->Title2[proper].mkv
Movie- Epilogue/
->MOVIE EPILOGUE .AVI
Media Movie/
->MEDIAMOVIE.CD1.mkv
->MEDIAMOVIE.CD2.mkv
```

.
.
.

Desired directory tree:

```
Proper Movie Title/
->Proper Movie Title.avi
->Proper Movie Title.srt
Title 2.mkv
Movie- Epilogue.avi
Media Movie/
->Media Movie.cd1.mkv
->Media Movie.cd2.mkv
```

Though this would be an ideal, my main wish is for the directories with only a single movie file within to have that file be renamed and moved into the parent directory.

My current approach is to use a double for loop in a .sh file, but I'm currently having a hard time keeping new bash knowledge in my head.

Help would be appreciated.

My current code (Just to get access to the internal movie files):

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=./*
for f in $FILES
do
        if [[ -d $f ]]; then
                INFILES=$f/*
                for file in $INFILES
                do
                        echo "Processing >$file< folder..."
                done
        #cat $f
        fi
done
```

Comment: Quick solution is to say no to piracy!! Buy movies and they will have proper titles.

Comment: Show what you've tried, we're not here to write your code for you.

Comment: Added the code I'm thinking through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something simple:

```
find * -type f -maxdepth 1 | while read file
do
    dirname="$(dirname "$file")"
    new_name="${dirname##*/}"
    file_ext=${file##*.}
    if [ -n "$file_ext" -a  -n "$dirname" -a -n "$new_name" ]
    then
        echo "mv '$file' '$dirname/$new_name.$file_ext'"
    fi
done
```

The `find *` says to run find on all *items* in the current directory. The `-type f` says you only are interested in files, and `-maxdepth 1` limits the depth of the search to the immediate directory.

- The `${file##*.}` is using a *pattern* match. The `##` says the largest left hand match to `*.` which is basically pulling everything off to the file extension.
- The `file_dir="$(dirname "$file")"` gets the directory name.
- Note quotes everywhere! You have to be careful about white spaces.

By the way, I `echo` instead of doing the actual move. I can pipe the output to a file, examine that file and make sure everything looks okay, then run that file as a shell script.

Comment: This is great, David. Thanks a lot.
Is there a surefire way to detect how many files are within a directory? The "| wc" command seems to not return the number of files, rather returning the number of words within a directory.

I'd like to have a conditional that only executes the given code if there are <=2 files in the directory.

Comment: @SWPhantom The command `wc -l` will return the _lines_, and not the words. See `man wc` for all of the various options.